# R Looping through a specific column and replace the value with random value from an array if meet a critieria

Tags: r, arrays, loops

I have a CSV file which consisted of 10000 rows of data. I need to perform loop through a specific column and replace the value if it meets the criteria with the particular value.
If it meet the criteria which is NA and will be selected the random selection of the value from the array which

```
Name     Age    Sex
Alice    20     M
James    NA     F
Jerome   30     M
Alex     25     M
Bruce    NA     M
Tan      45     M
Olive    25     F
Jasmine  37     F
```

My code is found below.

```
result <- array(c(50,24,12,30,60,16,71,81))
for (i in 2:ncol(mydata))
{
    if (mydata[ ,i] is.NA())
    {
        mydata[ ,i] == sample(result)

    }
    else 
    {
        next
    }
}
```

I tried this code below

```
array <- c("50","24","12","30","60","16","71","81") df$Age <- df$Age %>% 
replace_na(sample(array,1)).
```

The output replace the NA with the value 60 and another one 60 as well. It still remain the same. I tried running the code again and again. It still shows 60.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's do a `tidyverse` approach. It replaces any `NA` in the `Age` column with a random selection of values in `result`.

```
library(tidyverse)

result <- c(50,24,12,30,60,16,71,81)

df %>% mutate(Age = ifelse(is.na(as.numeric(as.character(Age))), 
                           sample(result, sum(is.na(Age))), 
                           Age))
```

## Output

```
     Name Age Sex
1   Alice  20   M
2   James  12   F
3  Jerome  30   M
4    Alex  25   M
5   Bruce  24   M
6     Tan  45   M
7   Olive  25   F
8 Jasmine  37   F
```

Comment: It produces an error, Warning message:
Problem with `mutate()` column `Age`.
i `Age = replace_na(Age, sample(array, 1))`.
i invalid factor level, NA generated

Comment: Seems like your `Age` column is `factor`. Try `df %>% mutate(Age = replace_na(as.numeric(as.character(Age)), sample(result, 1)))`. Also it would be nice if you could provide the result of `dput(df)`, in this case there will not be confusion of the data type.

Comment: If I am replacing the value with string value like abcd what will it be like

Comment: I have tried this code, array <- c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7")
df$Age <- df$Age %>% replace_na(sample(array,1)). It replace the NA with the values but however the value seem to be the same. Not random at all.

Comment: Take a look at `?set.seed`, it's just a way to make sure my random and your random is the same. Do not use `set.seed(1)` if you are generating "real" random

Comment: It still shows the same value. everytime I set.seed(0)

Comment: I set the code, set.seed(NULL) and it is still not working

Comment: If it still doesn't work, try deleting the line with `set.seed()` and re-launch `R`

Comment: I have restarted the R session and did not use set.seed(). The values are still the same.

Comment: I miss understood your question previously. It should work fine now, different `Name` with `NA` would have different output now.

Answer (score 0):

You may do this with the help of this helper function which can be applied with the help of `lapply` to multiple columns.

```
set.seed(2022)

replace_NA <- function(x, arr) {
  x[is.na(x)] <- sample(arr, sum(is.na(x)), replace = TRUE)
  x
}

mydata[-1] <- lapply(mydata[-1], replace_NA, result)
mydata

#     Name Age Sex
#1   Alice  20   M
#2   James   4   F
#3  Jerome  30   M
#4    Alex  25   M
#5   Bruce   3   M
#6     Tan  45   M
#7   Olive  25   F
#8 Jasmine  37   F
```